# Use a stepper to give a limit to the number of objects that can be inside an array (swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I have an array in my VC

```
var list : [QCategoryy] = [QCategoryy]()
list = NearbyPlaces.getCategories()
```

where `getCategories()` is

```
static func getCategories() -> [QCategoryy] {
        let list:[QCategoryy] = [QCategoryy(name: "bar", image: UIImage(named: "bar_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name :"night_club", image: UIImage(named: "nightclub_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "movie_theater", image: UIImage(named: "cinema_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "restaurant", image: UIImage(named: "restaurant_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "gym", image: UIImage(named: "gym_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "spa", image: UIImage(named: "spa_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "museum", image: UIImage(named: "museum_button.png")!)]
        return list
    }
```

but i would like that in my viewController the user can choose the maximum number of objects that must be in this array with a stepper `Int(steppeR.value)` (for example if the value of the stepper is 1, in my `list` can be only the first item of `getCategories`) I also already have an extension for shuffle the array

```
extension MutableCollection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    /// Shuffles the contents of this collection.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }

        for (firstUnshuffled , unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            let d: IndexDistance = numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
            guard d != 0 else { continue }
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            self.swapAt(firstUnshuffled, i)
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    /// Returns an array with the contents of this sequence, shuffled.
    func shuffled() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }
}
```

because i do not want that with the limitation there are always the same items. How can i do something like this?

Comment: Why don't you use a second filtered list based on your main list and the choice of the number of elements from the user. Meaning, you have your main list with all the objects possible and then the user chooses 1 in your filtered list you just add the first element of your main list...

Comment: can you please do an example of this? i understand i little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your `static func getCategories()` you initialize your main `list` right ?
Then, when the user changes the value of the stepper `Int(steppeR.value)`, you create a filtered list with only the number of objects needed :

```
//stepper is equal to 1
var filteredList = [QCategoryy]()
filteredList.append(list[0])
//stepper is equal to 3
var filteredList = [QCategoryy]()
for i in 0..<3 {
  filteredList.append(list[i])
}
```

Comment: ok understand and where i have to add this filteredList.append(list[0]) for i in 0..<3 {
  filteredList.append(list[i])
}  in the viewDidload or where

Comment: I think the best place to put it this statement is whenver the user changes your stepper value. The user can change it only once ? Or multiple times ?

Comment: Put a didSet listener on your stepper variable. Then, when it changes you update your filtered list.

Comment: the user can change the value of the stepper multiple times

Comment: Alright so i think the best is to put a didSet listener in your stepper variable like this : var stepper = //Put a default value { didSet { // update your filtered list } }